# Why is the OData $batch request in my SAPUI5 application failing?

Tags: odata, sapui5, wildfly

I have an OData v2 service running on Wildfly. This service is connected to a single table in SQL Server. Querying this service's metadata and table data in Postman works great. I believe the OData service itself is working like it should.

I have an SAPUI5 application that is pointing to the service (called `SITEDATA`) in the descriptor:

```
"sap.app": {
    ...,
    "dataSources": {
        "SAM": {
            "uri": "http://localhost:8080/odata/SITEDATA/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0"
            }
        }
    },...

"sap.ui5": {
    ...,
    "models": {
        ...,
        "perDiem": {
            "dataSource": "SAM"
        }...
```

I have a very simple view that points to the single table (which is also called SITEDATA):

```
    <List 
    items="{ path : 'perDiem>/SITEDATA' }">
    ...
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem title="{perDiem>SITE_ID}">
```

When I run the application I can see that the application successfully queries the service for:

- `http: //localhost:8080/odata/SITEDATA/$metadata`
- `http: //localhost:8080/odata/SITEDATA/SITEDATA?$skip=0&$top=100`

...as well as a bunch of other things. But then I get this:

[image: Request URL: http://localhost:8080/odata/SITEDATA/$batch, Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error]

The WildFly log shows that `SITEDATA/$batch` just doesn't exist. However, `localhost:8080/odata/SITEDATA/SITEDATA/$batch` works just fine.

And after researching this problem for days it looks like yes, the $`batch` request should be performed on the table, not the service. So the error makes sense. But I can't find any way to fix this.

Has any one experienced this problem or see anything I need to do to correct it?

Comment: If you get an "Internal Server Error" can you check transaction ST22?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid $batch calls to your backend I suggest you to explicitly declare your model as:

```
    "perDiem": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
        "settings": {
            "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
            "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
            "defaultCountMode": "Inline",
            "useBatch": false
        },
        "dataSource": "SAM",
        "preload": true
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to successfully complete a $batch call that includes a call to `/SITEDATA` endpoint? `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` class initializes the model to use batch calls by default. You can disable it by adding `"useBatch": false` to your model definition in the descriptor. You can try that to see if the problem is with the batch call.